# Windows 7 stopped connecting to samba share

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, samba

I have a problem with Windows 7 Home connecting to samba on linux server. It's worked fine for a year and without any changes in configuration or updates it suddenly stopped working. The strangest thing for me is that it stopped working for no reason that I could think of. 
After a few minutes after trying to connect I get:

```
\\ip is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource.       Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
```

Other computers in that network (XP machines) connect to samba without any problem.

I've tried adding LmCompatibilityLevel as described here: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/75-63-windows-samba-issue , but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem, it had to do with MS Live Essentials(MSN in particular, you can google and find a ton of articles on it), and there being a bug in Samba itself.  If you have Live Essentials installed, uninstall it and see if it works.